# Transform XML with XSLT in Node.js

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt

I want to transform a XML file by using a XSLT file in a Node.js environment. I searched a lot, but couldn't find anything useful. Are there any libraries that are easy to use and are able to perform such a transformation?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: The first result in a Google search showed "xslt-processor" https://github.com/fiduswriter/xslt-processor maybe it can be useful for you